# Easy Deploying of Python and application in one Bundle , For Linux

Tags: python, linux, deployment, portability, portable-applications

I Develop Fairly large python application on server side , with all database connect , files extraction , parsing , command line calls.

It becomes a nightmare for deploying as i used many third party modules outside of standard python lib. And i lost track of them . Especially Differnt Linux OS uses different version of them so it is no longer good to install them using OS's  package manager.

I want to deploy them in all one bundle including current python version i am using (Most OS Still ship with Python 2.5,6 i am using 2.7 and 2.7 specific features.) .

Further more , i have to teach the client to how to deploy , so they can test out in other servers. But they are not linux experts . I have to make it easy , in one script or by doing copy and paste.

There is Portablepython for Windows But there's nothing for Linux. And i had never used python Packaging  as i usually work on server that i only host.

Please enlighten me of avaliable packaging and deployment options for python , that includes all the installed python modules and python itself.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/distutils/builtdist.html

Comment: take a look at [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).

Comment: what i have see . does pyinstaller installs necessary packages online? I want to bundle exact versions of packages. Would pyinstaller help? Most of my packages are not in it's supported modules list so hmm.. i think it wont work ?

Comment: How about python version , it makes executable so that works without python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most Python packages can be deployed by creating a `lib` or similar directory in your deployment, and adding it to `sys.path` in Python, or `PYTHONPATH` outside, then copying the package directory (usually *inside* the directory you unzipped) into that directory. This lets you keep the package with your deployed code, say, in a Mercurial repository.

Deploying Python itself is going to be a bit more hassle, but if you can control where it's installed (such as `/usr/local` or `/opt`), then it's just a matter of `./configure --prefix=...`, `make`, and `sudo make install`. Then you can point your scripts to that Python by starting them with a line like `#!/usr/local/bin/python`, as long as the script is marked executable.

For example, if you were deploying code that needs `docutils`, then you'd do something like:

```
cd projectDir
mkdir -p lib
tar xzvf ~/Downloads/docutils-0.8.tgz
mv docutils-0.8/docutils lib
rm -r docutils-0.8
```

Then a Python module in this directory would just add the following at the start:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import os
import sys
sys.path(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), "lib"))
import docutils
```

Comment: thats interesting. So can i also copy all from site-packages into Lib and do sys.path ? Thanks for the trick. How about bundling my own python version , how that can be solved?

Comment: Second paragraph of my answer. You'll probably want to use a directory that doesn't exist on the target machine, such as `/opt/python2.7` so you don't have to sort out Python's files from other installs. Once it's installed on your machine, `cd /opt; tar cjvf /tmp/python2.7.tar.bz2 python2.7`, then ship `/tmp/python2.7.tar.bz2` to them as part of your delivery, then on their end do `mkdir -p /opt; cd /opt; sudo tar xjpf /tmp/python2.7.tar.bz2` to install it. Then your executable scripts just need to start with `#!/opt/python2.7/bin/python`

Comment: Thanks a lot  , after a year it make most sense. Virtualenv do not work for my needs. This one works. Only one problem , should i do static compile of python coz some linux have different Libc

Comment: That's a tough one. My feeling is "no"; you should be using the system-installed Python, or you should use `#!/usr/bin/env python` as your initial line, which makes it use whatever Python is in the $PATH (so the user can then set that up themselves). Shipping a Python binary is just going to be support pain; there will *always* be some Linux install out there that breaks it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a broad topic, but here are some pointers.

For your Python project and it's dependencies, have a look at [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), and [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip).

Virtualenv provides an isolated python environment on your target platform that you can then install your project into.

Pip is a package installation tool that will download and install your package and its the dependencies. Have a look at pip freeze to provide a quick way of defining a list of dependencies that you currently have installed in your development environment.

If you want to learn more about package distribution in Python then you should also read up about the [distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) project.

For the non-python components of the system, including installing python itself, a system automation tool like [Puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/) can be used, but sounds like it might be overkill for your needs. If you are looking for a one-step installation, you should probably be looking into building a package for your target system's [package manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_management_system).

Comment: You need to be careful with downloading and installing dependencies, because there's no guarantee that the version you developed against is the version that will be downloaded on delivery. I had that problem once, when I developed a Django app using South 0.6, and 0.7 shipped the day before delivery, and made some big API changes, so deployment didn't work.  Keeping the dependencies with the deployment solved that problem.

Comment: With virtualenv , does it make an enviorment that can be copy-pasted into another Server (with same OS ofcoz) ? I mean does it include whole python enviorment + all other necessary packages ? With PIP . as Mike DeSimone stated , theres chance of running into incompatibility problems (as i have deployed on 4 separate servers i have encounters 2 times already ) . I will also look into puppet . thanks a lot.

Comment: @V3ss0n I'm afraid you can't just copy a virtualenv from one server to another and expect it to "just work". Have a look at [this](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv#making-environments-relocatable) for a better explanation of why.

Comment: @Mike have you tried specifying the version number of the package you want? `pip install south==0.6` will only install version 0.6 of south, even if 0.7 is available.

Comment: @v3ss0n There is more than one way to specify the dependencies of your project. Here is [one way](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/#requirements-files), and here is [another](http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#declaring-dependencies). Pip works with both.

Comment: @Pinballkid: I've never used `pip` nor is it installed on my Mac or Linux system. That said, if the devs decide to pull an old version off their site, and that's the one I use, then I could be in trouble...

Answer (score 0):

> I want to deploy them in all one module including current python version i am using (Most OS Still ship with Python 2.5,6 i am using 2.7 and 2.7 specific features.) .

May be VirtualEnv is what you need for this?

Comment: Oops.. I see great answer above. :)

Comment: VirtualEnv , does it eliminate the need of existing python installation ? I heard it is used for shared hosting of python.

Comment: No, virtualenv builds on top of an existing python installation and hence requires that python already be installed on the system.

Comment: so ok install python on target system and then deploy python enviorment created using virtual env? seems simple but still cant bundle everything.

Answer (score -4):

There's no reason for Super Simple Server Side Setup.

Don't waste time on that.

How many server installations will happen?  Not many.

Sys admins expect a certain level of complexity in server-based applications.

You have a list of 3rd party packages; they follow that list and do the installs.

Then -- after they've done all the installs -- they install and configure your package.

That's what many sys admins who work on servers expect.   They expect dependencies and they expect a multi-step install.

Comment: I'm not the guy who downvoted, but I have rarely been lucky enough to have a knowledgeable sysadmin on the other end of a delivery. Usually it's the lowest-ranking software guy who barely knows how to use Linux, much less install it beyond "drop in a Fedora CD and hit OK for everything". If something goes wrong, their procedure is 1) blame me, so I have to prove that my delivery is not at fault, then 2) wait while their guy finds someone with a clue... while I'm being blamed for the delay. Sometimes you need to oversimplify deployments for the customer, just to keep sane.

Comment: I've had sysadmins who did not trust super-sophisticated installers, but required the base list of packages available through YUM or YAST.  No exceptions.   No bundling.  They weren't geniuses.  But they required packages from repositories and would not take bundled installations from me.

Comment: S.Lott , as i mentioned , the guys at target enviorment who is far away from me , other side of the world. They have ZERO Linux knowledge... So it gotta be as simple as possible. In short if i can pack everything into a zip and let them extract and run the python file to start . Thats what kind of thing i will need.

Comment: They only want something very simple to deploy. And there gonna be many installations as they install it on Their Client's Office enviorments.

Comment: @S.Lott: If something is available through YUM or YAST, and you're using the same distro release for testing and production, then you're most of the way there. I've had to deal with the opposite: "We don't want to contaminate our install with your dependencies; they might break something." So it depends on who is on the receiving end. The customer is always right... dang it. Then there are packages only available via SF or `python setup.py install` or `easy_install`... easier to bundle those with the delivery than worry about conflicts with existing packages.

Comment: @Mike yeah , it wont work for me as most of my packages dont come from Package managers at all. Also ESPECIALLY Standard python version is too outdated for most of the package repos , thats too faustrating . almost every OS still use 2.5 and 2.6 of python. My installation needs python 2.7 so that it is best to run with its own python and do not overwrites OS's version. thats why i need to bring it along in a bundle. and there are packages i use that have to download and run setup.py , cant even get from easy_install/pip, just as you saids.